# Не выполняется файл миграции

Tags: laravel

Здравствуйте!

На \выполнить миграцию\ - ошибка и такой ответ в консоли:

```
$ php artisan migrate
"select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ? and table_name = ?"
"select `migration` from `migrations` order by `batch` asc, `migration` asc"
"select max(`batch`) as aggregate from `migrations`"

[ErrorException]
Use of undefined constant users - assumed 'users'
```

В чем проблема??
Спасибо!

Comment: Найдите в программе слово "users" и оберните его в кавычки.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос файл миграции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле миграции вы обращаетесь к полям таблицы по имени.
Имя поля - это строковая константа, а не переменная, поэтому нужно обернуть его в кавычки как любую строку, например `$_POST[users]` заменить на `$_POST['users']` (в одинарных или в двойных кавычках, как вам удобнее).